# Is Azure App Service editor available on Linux App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-linux

The app service editor is available on Windows App Service. However, I am not able to identify it on Linux App Service. The /dev route on the scm of the app service is supposed to bring up the App Service Editor. But for Linux App Service, the route is not registered. I'm doing some quick experiments  and do want to deploy every time I make small changes. I'm on the free tier of the app service. Will moving to a paid one helps ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that the app service editor is still not available on Linux App Service. There is an [old blog](https://petri.com/azure-app-services-linux) mentioned it even some features have updated(Networking).

[image]

You also could see the app service editor does not exist on the P1V2 price tier.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Nancy, there is no edit in the Linux version, but may you use `bash` instead.

Using `bash` you can **edit** the files of your application through a `bash` editor, such as `nano` or `vim`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session

An alternative is using `FTP` to manage your files.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp